# Webpack не коректно сохраняет имена файлов

Tags: webpack, webpack5

Нужна помощь, Webpack5  заменяет заполнитель [name] на [id] у файлов подключенных через импорт в index.js
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
чего я хочу: добится что бы файл назывался просто main.css, но webpack имя строит из пути до файла(т.е все папки в которых изначально лежит источник)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и получается public\assets\css\src_assets_css_main_css.css
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой конфиг

```
const filename = (ext) => devMode ? `[name].${ext}` : `[name].${ext}`;module.exports = {

devtool,

target: target,

mode: 'development',

context: way.public,

entry: {
    public: [way.src + '/js/index.js'],
    test: way.src + '/js/test.js'
},

output: {
    filename: 'assets/js/' + filename('js'),
    path: way.public,
    clean: true,
},

devServer: {
    static: {
        directory: way.html,
    },
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 9000,
},

resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@root': path.resolve(__dirname, way.root),
        '@html': path.resolve(__dirname, way.html),
        '@css': path.resolve(__dirname, way.src + "/css"),
        '@scss': path.resolve(__dirname, way.src + "/scss/"),
        '@js': path.resolve(__dirname, way.src + "/js/"),
        '@lib': path.resolve(__dirname, way.src + "/lib/"),
    }
},

optimization: optimization(),

plugins: [].concat(
    htmlPageNames.map((page) => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: way.html + `/${page.path}/${page.name}`,
        filename: way.public + `/${page.path}/${page.name}`,
        favicon: way.html + '/assets/img/svg/tel.svg',
        inject: true,
    })),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'assets/css/' + filename('css'),
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            {from: way.src + "/lib", to: way.assets + "/lib"},
        ],
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
),
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(c|sa|sc)ss$/i,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {loader: "css-loader", options: {sourceMap: true}},
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: {
                        postcssOptions: {
                            plugins: [require("postcss-preset-env")],
                        }
                    }
                },
                {loader: "sass-loader", options: {sourceMap: true}},
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: "defaults"}]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)?$/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
                filename: 'assets/fonts/[name][ext]'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "image-webpack-loader",
                options: {
                    mozjpeg: {
                        progressive: true,
                    },
                    optipng: {
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                    pngquant: {
                        quality: [0.65, 0.90],
                        speed: 4
                    },
                    gifsicle: {
                        interlaced: false,
                    },
                    webp: {
                        quality: 75
                    }
                }
            }],
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
                filename: 'assets/img/[name][ext]'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(svg)$/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
                filename: 'assets/img/svg/[name][ext]'
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

}